# How to develop an effective notation for a partially ordered logic?

Tags: lo.logic, notation, sequent-calculus, natural-deduction

I am developing a logic for reasoning about programs in a resource-constrained environment. My starting point is intuitionistic linear logic, but I made the following changes:

1. In intuitionistic linear logic, environments are sets of available resources. In my logic, environments are partially ordered sets: some resources have to be consumed before others.

   - Multiplicative conjunction splits into two connectives: parallel conjunction and sequential conjunction.
   - Linear implication can only consume a resource X, if there is no other resource Y that must be consumed before X.
2. Logical connectives are usually defined in terms of introduction and elimination rules. In my logic, I need a new kind of rule: *usage rules*, which describe how a resource can be used in a computation without destroying it.

   - I add a new unary operator, called [borrowed pointer](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/guide-lifetimes.html), which denotes a non-owning reference to an existing resource.
   - Creating a borrowed pointer *uses* but does not consume the resource being pointed. In particular, one may always create a borrowed pointer to an existing resource X, even if there is some resource Y that must be consumed before X.
   - No resource may be consumed until all borrowed pointers to it have been consumed. This is my main motivation for introducing the notion of sequential conjunction in the first place.

I want to give a formal presentation of the rules of inference of this logic using natural deduction and sequent calculus. However, I am having trouble coming up with a good notation that succinctly conveys ideas like:

1. The environment $\Gamma$ can be split into sub-environments $\Delta, \Sigma$, where there is no resource in $\Sigma$ that must be consumed before any resource in $\Delta$.
2. Given the environment $\Gamma$ and a resource $A \in \Gamma$, the result of adding a resource ${\rm ref} A$ to $\Gamma$, in such a way that ${\rm ref} A$ must be consumed before $A$.
3. The sequential conjunction of $A$ and $B$.
4. etc.

What guidelines should I follow in order to design a good notation for this logic?

Comment: There is no absolute notion of good presentation. It all depends on what you want to do with it. For proving meta-theorems like cut-elimination, a sequent style presentation might be suitable. For actual reasoning maybe natural deduction is more appropriate. Etc.

Comment: @MartinBerger: The ultimate goal is using this logic as the basis for a type system for a functional language for systems programming.

Comment: Typing systems are often easily seen as logics presented in natural deduction style.

Comment: Maybe the sequent calculus for multiplicative [noncommutative logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_logic) by [Abrusci and Ruet](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-0072(99)00014-7) may be an inspiration?

Comment: @DamianoMazza: Thanks, I am going to have a look.